# Ubuntu 16.04 on Surface Pro 4, cant enter disk encryption password on typecover

Tags: 16.04, surface

I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Surface Pro 4 and during the install choose to encrypt the entire disk. During boot up at grub the typecover works, once booted the typecover works, during boot when prompted for the disk encryption password I cannot enter it using the typecover, I can only enter it if I use an external USB keyboard which will make using the Surface a pain. I hope someone knows of a fix for this so I dont have to reinstall and not use full disk encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It could because the way the typecover operates or that the developers haven't been implemented it yet, etc. Type covers tend to operate differently than regular PS2 or USB keyboards. If I were you I'd just use a standard USB Keyboard. :)

Comment: I figured out a way to incorporate a usb key for the encryption so I can during boot plug in the USB and it will give the key and boot up, not extremely secure but usable, not really going to store highly sensitive stuff on this box